# Unique pointers xvalue Semantics? Why is the behavior of lambda f2 different from lambda f1?

Tags: c++, lambda, c++14

I want to clear my understanding of unique pointer xvalue arguments

This is a example code I wrote to learn std::move and unique pointers . Can  anyone explain why line2 crashes but line1 works ? What does moving do in lambda f2 in my test program , Why does line1 work even after a std::move ? This is just for my learning and not a homework problem , i am very new to C++14 and C++11

```
#include <iostream>
#include <functional>
#include <memory>

void test()
{

    std::unique_ptr<int> p (new int(278));
    auto f1 = [](std::unique_ptr<int> i){std::cout << *i << std::endl;};
    auto f2 = [](std::unique_ptr<int> &&i){std::cout << *i << std::endl;};

    f2(std::move(p));
    std::cout << *p << std::endl;    //line 1

    f1(std::move(p));
    std::cout << *p << std::endl;    //line 2
}  

int main(int argc, const char * argv[]) {
    test();
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: added the edits , it didn't compile because I didn't add the header includes

Comment: I am pasting the entire code from Xcode Version 7.2 . Yes sorry that is a typo . I am very sorry

Comment: Apple LLVM 7.0 , I corrected the typos in endl . Thank you for the catch

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Line 1 works because std::move is just a cast to r-value reference. Actual transfering ownership is usually done by move constructor or move assignment operator, neither of which is in f2. Line 2 crashes because passing argument by value in f1 calls  move constructor, after which unique_ptr is empty.